# iOS 6.1.5 UITextField - text not populating

Tags: ios, uitextfield

My customer has a POS (Enterprise) app that was working fine on iPod6.1.3. Some of the devices were upgraded to 6.1.5 last week and began exhibiting a problem with taps on the keyboard not populating the UITextField. Unfortunately it is an intermittent problem and I do not have reliable steps to replicate, but I have seen it happen on a 6.1.5. device while running under the debugger. Here's what I know:

1. User taps on any of 7 UITextFields on the view. Keyboard slides up from bottom. Cursor starts blinking in the field.
2. User taps any key (including return). The key popover shows the key being pressed. Nothing appears in the UITextField.
3. Once the problem starts, it will persist until I quit the app (in this case, the app really quits with an exit(0) - required due to credit card security). Running the app again will most likely work correctly.

In the debugger, when things are working correctly I get callbacks to textFieldShouldBeginEditing:, textFieldDidEndEditing:, textFieldShouldReturn:, and textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString: as expected. When things don't work, I DO get callbacks for textFieldShouldBeginEditing: and  textFieldDidEndEditing:, but I DO NOT get call backs for textFieldShouldReturn:, and textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:. I checked the delegate for the UITextField in the shouldBegin and DidEnd methods - they are of course set to self.

Again, this behavior is new, and only in iOS6.1.5. There is nothing "fancy" going on in the view controller.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this after going to background and returning to App? We've hit a bug in Apple's keyboard implementation which sometimes causes this. But we've hit it on iOS6 in general and it exists somewhat in iOS7. Are more than one window involved?

Comment: 1. No, app never goes to background - it does exit(0) in app delegate anytime it gets applicationDidEnterBackground (due to credit card security requirements). 2. I'm told the Apple Keyboard comes up in its own window, but there is only 1 app window.